# BPEL Assign expression count(nodes) returns double

Tags: wso2, bpel, wso2-business-process

Using wso2bps-3.5.1

The count() of nodes in my Assign activity is assigned to an Integer typed element (verifyTerminationRequest/connections):

```
<bpel:copy>
    <bpel:from expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">
        <![CDATA[count($closeAccountResponse.closeAccountResponsePart/xclac:accountConnections/xcom:accountConnection)]]>
    </bpel:from>
    <bpel:to part="parameters" variable="verifyTerminationRequest">
        <bpel:query queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0"><![CDATA[wvete:verifyTerminationRequestMessage[1]/wvete:connections]]></bpel:query>
    </bpel:to>
</bpel:copy>
```

For some reason the resulting message looks like this:

```
<verifyTerminationRequest xmlns="http://seb.se/ops/ica/vete/wsdl">
    <ax2410:verifyTerminationRequestMessage xmlns:ax2410="http://seb.se/ops/ica/vete/wsdl">
        <ax2410:connections>2.0</ax2410:connections>
    </ax2410:verifyTerminationRequestMessage>
</verifyTerminationRequest>
```

And verifyTerminationRequestMessage/connections = 2.0 throws an exception:

```
Fault Name  {http://seb.se/ops/ica/vete/wsdl}UnknownFault
Fault Data  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><message>
    <Fault>
        <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
        <faultstring>java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2.0"</faultstring>
    </Fault>
</message>
Error Line  356
```

Why?

I've tried with round(count(...)) with no success.

Answer (score 0):

try number function - number(count()) it works for me.

Comment: I still have the same problem since number(count(...)) returns 2.0 and my backend service throws NumberFormatException.